# Finding parameterization of circle in plane from center

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm looking to find a parameterization of a unit circle in R3 centered at (1, -1, 3) and in the plane x+2y-z+4 = 0. How do I approach this?

I've thought of trying to find the intersection between the sphere and the plane, but I don't know where I would start.

Answer (score 0):

Think first about the standard unit circle parameterisation:
$$r(\theta) = (\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta)), \quad \theta \in [0, 2\pi].$$
Now, think about it slightly differently:
$$r(\theta) = \cos(\theta) e_1 + \sin(\theta) e_2$$
where $e_1 = (1, 0)$ and $e_2 = (0, 1)$.

Now, think about the same parameterisation, but replacing $e_1, e_2$ with some other orthonormal set. Possibly in $\Bbb{R}^3$. Possibly even in the plane you're describing. If you want to move the centre to a different point $a$, then all you need is
$$r(\theta) = a + \cos(\theta) e_1 + \sin(\theta) e_2,$$
and you'll get a parameterisation of a unit circle centred at $a$, in the plane generated by orthonormal basis $e_1, e_2$. All you need to do now is find an orthonormal basis for your plane!